# problema con el navbar Boostrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap

tengo una situación rara con los estilos que usa boostrap 4, para la pagina que estoy haciendo, uso datatables y tabledit, estos los tengo con versiones anteriores de css del boostrap4:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

al usar esta versión(arriba), todo el sitio se ve correcto excepto el navbar que se reduce su tamaño en 3/4 (imagen: sombra amarilla como debería de ser, verde como carga) y los botones de editar y borrar del tabledit se ven y funcionan correctamente.

[image: Navbar version 3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css]

ahora, cuando cambio la versión del min.css por la que hay en la pagina de boostrap, la pagina pierde el estilo, el navbar se arregla los botones del tabledit se desaparecen

versión actual en boostrap 4:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con la versión 3.3.6 (abajo), se ve todo correcto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En conclusión: al cambiar por la versión 4.5.2 arregla el navbar pero no funciona el tabledit con sus botones y daña el estilo de la pagina, con la versión 3.3.6 el navbar se reduce pero mantiene el estilo de la pagina y mantiene los botones del tabledit.

Alguna idea de que hacer?

Comment: Puedes re-crear el estilo que quieres usando tu propio CSS.

Comment: pero no los toma, ya lo hice, y el navbar no se ve afectado por el css externo

Comment: Bueno, necesito un [mre] para realizar la prueba y detectar el error

Comment: De Bootstrap 3 a Bootstrap 4 hay un proceso de refactorización bastante arduo. No se resolverá agregando o quitando sólo un par de cosas. Saludos

Comment: tabledit.js funciona sobre la versión 3 de Bootstrap, por eso al actualizar la versión no te funciona como debería. Lo mejor es siempre tener tus librerías actualizadas, esto con el fin de ser escalables con el tiempo. Ahora, si quieres conservar tabledit sobre BS3, lo mejor es hacer lo que te recomienda Excorpion, crear tu propio CSS, añade clases personalizadas